plugin 'com.android.library' not found
I am trying to import the tess two library into my existing Android Studio Jellyfish program, and there seems to be a build error, 'plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':eyes-two'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.

I tried including code blocks in build.gradle which I found in other stack exchange solutions, but nothing seemed to work. What can I try next? This is my Android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3' // 1.3.0-beta2
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
develocity {
    buildScan {
        termsOfUseUrl.set("https://gradle.com/help/legal-terms-of-use")
        termsOfUseAgree.set("yes")
    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

and this is my app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.android.library"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:9.1.0'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}



def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.cybersafehaven.arishta"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

